# Upgrading rails to the latest version from 2.3.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The command:

```
rails -v
```

gives me `Rails 2.3.5`.

How can I upgrade to the latest version? I have tried `sudo gem update` but get "nothing to update".

Answer (score 2):

Rails is a gem. So you can update it by using:

```
gem install rails -v 2.3.14
```

That will install the current version of the Rails 2 line. If that does not work, you first have to install Rubygems. See the [Ubuntu Ruby Help Page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RubyOnRails#Installing_RubyGems) for help how to do this.

The current version is 3.2. You can install it with:

```
gem install rails # (chooses the latest automatically)
```

or with:

```
gem install rails -v 3.2.6 # latest today
```

If you have a Rails application you also need to change your `Gemfile` (it is in the applications' root folder).

The change from version 2 to 3 can be a tough task. See the [Railscast on Upgrading to Rails 3](http://railscasts.com/episodes/225-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-1) for more information.

Comment: can I delete and start again?

Comment: I am nit sure if I understand your question. Normally it is not needed to rewrite the full application for upgrading. But if you just started writing a Rails 2-Application, you should not go on with it and start a Rails 3 application from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent railscast on this: http://railscasts.com/episodes/225-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-1

It's basically easy and you should not be afraid if your codebase is small, however it can involve rewriting some of your existing code.

Answer (score 0):

Rails 3 introduces a number of changes and I wish you the best of luck as my experience it has been a pain to do.  But, I recommend starting out by visiting [railscasts.com](http://railscasts.com) and watching [episode #255 - Upgrading to to Rails 3 part 1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/225-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-1).

If I remember right most of it involves downloading rails `gem install rails -v 3.2.6` then running `rails new .` inside your directory and making sure you don't override what you need.  Then making sure your gems are up to date and compatible if not either upgrading them or completly replacing them with another that does the same thing.